# Why are dimensions regarded as square/perpendicular?

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, spacetime-dimensions

Starting from the second dimension, the dimensions are basically represented by a square, cube, tesseract, and so on. I don't know if this is a stupid question or not, but is there an obvious or less-obvious reason why the representations of the dimensions are square?

Comment: It's not a requirement; the typical definition is topological in origin, and the existence of boundaries.  Perpendicularity is merely a convenience; non-orthogonal coordinates are used in crystallography when they are more convenient.

Comment: Although that non-orthogonality makes certain thing (e.g. 3D rotation of frame of reference) a real pain... Which is why most textbooks focus on cubic symmetric crystals.

Answer (score 4):

They are not always "square."  Orthogonal bases like you describe are convenient for many reasons, such as the fact that a "length" can be described in easy terms, and that there is only one way to notate any given point.

There are others, such as the polar coordinate system which are different.  The polar system describes 2 dimensions, one linear and one circular.  Locally, however, they are orthogonal, meaning wherever you have a linear (radial) axis crossing a circular (tangental) axis, they are at right angles.  This, once again, is for convenience.  A lot of systems are described as a "manifold" which is the general term for any system which looks square/perpendicular up close, but may have more complex structure from afar.

There are even cases where the axes are not orthogonal, such as crystallography as mentioned by Peter Diehr in comments above.  Once again, this is a matter of convenience.  We'd really like to handle everything in nice easy orthogonal bases, but in the case of crystallography, the actual behaviors of crystals are more easily understood with non-orthogonal axes.

In the end, its always a matter of convenience.  We use the strongest coordinate system that can describe the structure we are looking at, because it makes it easier to demonstrate facts using math.

As an example, it may not be obvious, but calculating the area of things in rectangular coordinates is *much* easier than calculating them in polar coordinates.  There's a term called the Jacobian that shows up if you have to integrate in polar coordinates to find surface area.  That term is 1 (or the identity matrix) for nice orthogonal axes.  Most of the time, we'd rather use the super easy rectangular coordinates.  However, if the shape we are trying to find the area of is easy to express in polar coordinates, but hard to express in rectangular, it may be worth digging out that pesky Jacobian term and doing the integration in polar.